# What does "sweater of conspiracy" mean?

Tags: meaning

> In the midst of Godzilla's attack on Apex Pensacola, I found some
> crazy  tech with no official classification. What I saw doesn't match
> any of the engineering specs I've ever seen. So what are they working
> on in such blackout secrecy, hmm? This could be the thread that
> finally unravels the Apex **sweater of conspiracy**.

What does "sweater of conspiracy" mean?

Apex is a facility's name.

Source: Godzilla vs. Kong (2021)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sweater is a garment knitted from wool. Knitted things often have the property that if you find a loose thread and pull it, the whole garment wholly or partly comes apart (the knitting unravels). The Apex conspiracy is being compared to something that can be pulled apart easily by action in one place. This way of comparing things is called a *metaphor*.

[image]